# Python Pandas Dataframe cell value split

Tags: pandas

I am lost on how to split the binary values such that each (0,1)value takes up a column of the data frame. 
[from jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J9Jm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3], 1:['1010','1100','0101']})
print (df)
   0     1
0  1  1010
1  2  1100
2  3  0101

df = pd.concat([df[0], 
                df[1].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).astype(int)],
                axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)

   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  0  1  0
1  2  1  1  0  0
2  3  0  1  0  1
```

Another solution with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.concat([df[0], 
                pd.DataFrame(df[1].apply(list).values.tolist()).astype(int)], 
                axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)

   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  0  1  0
1  2  1  1  0  0
2  3  0  1  0  1
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:['1010','1100','0101']}) 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[0].apply(list).values.tolist()).astype(int)
print (df1)
   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  1  0
1  1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0  1
```

But if need lists:

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in list(x)])
print (df)
              0
0  [1, 0, 1, 0]
1  [1, 1, 0, 0]
2  [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: what if is it just like this df = pd.DataFrame({0:['1010','1100','0101']}) ?